# Titanium hanging at "Creating a Titanium Project"

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am on a Mac, Snow Leopard 10.6 with Xcode installed. I installed titanium studio, and am trying to create a new mobile project. This hangs. (See screenshot). The folder gets created, but no files are being written.

In contrast a desktop project gets created. I will be glad to provide logs, but I have no idea where to get the logs from.

https://img.skitch.com/20110906-feigysa442sn4gggkabrxnjj4b.png

Answer (score 0):

my first suggestion is to select the latest mobile SDK, 1.7.2. The screen shot shows you using 1.5.x